# ¿Como puedo construir una lista concatenando una letra con un numero?

Tags: python, lista, concatenación

Lo que necesito hacer es crear múltiples listas concatenado cierta letra, con un numero, el cual podria ser asignado por un iterador en un ciclo for.

Por ejemplo, necesito crear 3 listas, me gustaría que están fuesen A1, A2 Y A3. Sin embargo el numero de listas que sea necesarias dependerán de un valor incierto.

tenia la idea de hacer algo como lo siguiente:

```py
P = 3.

for i in range(2):
    A + str(i) = []
```

Pero obviamente no funciona.

Espero puedan guiarme para conseguir lo que busco... desde ya gracias, saludos..

Answer (score 0):

La forma en que lo haces no es la correcta, para hacerlo tendríamos que especificar que el valore `A+str(i)` sea una variable, lo cual se puede pero no lo recomiendo, para este problema propongo usar un diccionario como estructura de dato donde `A+str(i)` será la clave y `[]` será el valor, recordemos que la estructura de un diccionario se base en `{clave:valor}` (es muy parecido a un JSON)

```py
dic = {} #aqui se almacenaran los valores

for i in range(2):
#definimos la calve
    dic[f"A{i}"] = [] #este es el valor

print(dic)
```

Aquí utilizamos *f-string* para concatenar, ya no hace falta convertir el numero a string pues al concatenarlo con un string ya se transforma en uno.
**resultado**

```
{'A0': [], 'A1': []}
```

También podemos resumir todo lo que escribimos antes a una sola linea utilizando una comprensión de diccionario.

```py
dic = {f"A{i}":[] for i in range(2)}
print(dic)
```

**resultado**

```
{'A0': [], 'A1': []}
```